# org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function

Tags: scala, apache-spark, nullpointerexception, apache-spark-sql

I new to *scala* and I am trying to execute the following code:

```
val SetID = udf{(c:String, d: String) =>
    if( c.UpperCase.contains("EXKLUS") == true)
    {d}
    else {""}
}
val ParquetWithID = STG1
  .withColumn("ID", SetID( col("line_item"), col("line_item_ID")))
```

both columns (`line_item` and `line_item_id`) are defined as `Strings` in the `STG1` Schema.

I get the following error when I try to run the code:

```
`org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function($anonfun$1$$anonfun$2: (string, string) => string)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:370)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:246)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$4.apply(SparkPlan.scala:240)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$1$$anonfun$apply$24.apply(RDD.scala:803)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

and

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyTests$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(MyTests.scala:356)
    at MyTests$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$2.apply(MyTests.scala:355)
    ... 16 more
```

I also tried `c.UpperCase().contains("EXKLUS")` but i got the same error.
However, if I simply run a "`if equals`" statement everything works fine. So I guess the problem is in using `UpperCase().contains(" ")` function in my `udf` but I do not understand where the problem comes from. Any help would be appriciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if the `schema` contains as

```
 |-- line_item: string (nullable = true)
 |-- line_item_ID: string (nullable = true)
```

then checking for `null` in your if statement should solve the issue as (note that there is `toUpperCase` method for strings)

```
val SetID = udf{(c:String, d: String) =>
  if(c != null && c.toUpperCase.contains("EXKLUS") == true)
  {d}
  else {""}
}
val ParquetWithID = STG1
  .withColumn("ID", SetID( col("line_item"), col("line_item_ID")))
```

I hope the answer is helpful

Comment: Great to hear that @Inna and thanks for accepting :)

Comment: any advice how to handle this UDF issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935600/writing-udf-for-looks-up-in-the-map-in-java-giving-unsupported-literal-type-clas